# Method not found: 'IntPtr System.Fabric.SecurityCredentialExtension.ToNative

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, stateful

I am trying to consume Stateful Service Fabric in my ASP.Net Core by following the example in the following demo:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-add-a-web-frontend

Unfortunately, when I run the code, I am ending up with the following error:

> Method not found: 'IntPtr
>   System.Fabric.SecurityCredentialExtension.ToNative(System.Fabric.SecurityCredentials,
>   System.Fabric.Interop.PinCollection)'.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
{
    ICounter counter =
        ServiceProxy.Create<ICounter>(new Uri("fabric:/MyApplication/MyStatefulService"), new ServicePartitionKey(0));

    long count = await counter.GetCountAsync(); //this where it is erroring

    return new string[] { count.ToString() };
}
```

I wonder if there is any solution to this issue. I am running the service cluster on my local machine.

thanks.

Comment: I have just run into the same problem following the same instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem. The fix was to upgrade all the nuget packages for the ASP.NET Core project to the latest versions. Then it just worked. For some reason when you create a new ASP.NET Core service it does not have the latest versions by default. You need to update them.